# Como trabalhar com Arrays utilizando o Angular 5 no console log?

Tags: angular

Estou tentando implementar um dropdown Multiselect dynamic no Angular, é como é selecionando estado de acordo com as cidades, se eu selecionar por exemplo PE no primeiro dropdown list ao ele vai me retorna automaticamente no dropdown list a lista de todas as cidade de Pernambuco se eu por acaso eu selecionar SP no primeiro dropdown list ai ele vai me retorna no segundo dropdown list a lista de todas as cidade de São Paulo e assim por diante.

Como tenho pouca experiência e não sei implementar isso, estou tentando fazer essa implementação por pedaços.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
 listarTodas(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.cidadesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => console.log(response.json()));
  }
```

Esse é o retorno em json:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Eu gostaria de retorna no **console** do navegador somente os
  atributos do **codigoEstado**
- Eu gostaria também de retorna no **console** do navegador somente
  **codigoEstado** que sejam de código **1**

Para mim é importante saber essas coisas pois quando eu começar a entender esses princípios de implementação eu vou poder ter condições de começar a implementar dropdown Multiselect

Comment: Você quer imprimir no console apenas os registros que tenham `codigoEstado === 1`? No exemplo dado, seria `{codigo: 1, nome: "Rio Branco", codigoEstado: 1}, {codigo: 2, nome: "Cruzeiro do Sul", codigoEstado: 1}`

Comment: primeiro quero agradecer em me ajuda, mas é isso mesmo que estou precisando!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a função [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

```js
listarTodas(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.cidadesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
          let resultado = response.json();
          console.log(resultado.filter(_ => _.codigoEstado === 1));
      });
}
```

Veja funcionando abaixo:

```js
const resultado = [
  { codigo: 1, nome: "Rio Branco", codigoEstado: 1 },
  { codigo: 2, nome: "Cruzeiro do Sul", codigoEstado: 1 },
  { codigo: 3, nome: "Salvador", codigoEstado: 2 },
  { codigo: 4, nome: "Porto Seguro", codigoEstado: 2 }
];

console.log(resultado.filter(_ => _.codigoEstado === 1));
```

Comment: não seguir fazer reconhecer o json()

Comment: @wladyband como assim, não funcionou?

Comment: Eu já entendi porque não funcionou, você colocou o valor do resultado como uma constante e fez um exemplo que deu certo, mas a culpa não é sua, foi o que eu tinha pedido no anunciado, mas que na verdade a minha necessidade era diferente, é porque eu me expressei mau. eu só sei que estou perdido.

Comment: eu não sei a quem recorrer e continuo com uma dúvida que é simples, mas até agora não apareceu uma alma caridosa para me ajuda, mas fica tranquilo, vou ficar aqui tentando até conseguir.